# Circumflex initialisation code (or: how to integrate Squeryl)

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/) with [Circumflex](http://circumflex.ru/). Squeryl requires some initialisation, but I'm a bit left in the dark on where and how I should put that initialisation code.

Is there a place where I can register startup methods or something?

Comment: How about your `main` method?